# T-SQL query to summarize total per month per year, and cumulative amounts to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table that captures every Sales Transaction:

```
Transactions 
(
    ID INT, 
    TransactionDate DATETIME, 
    SalesAmount MONEY
)
```

I want to write a **T-SQL** query which returns a report (snapshot sample below). First column it lists the month, next column Total-Sales per month within year, and last column cumulative amount of that year up to this month. Only for year of 2018.

Any thoughts or solutions? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: please show your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
( 
   Select 
   YEAR(TransactionDate) as [Year],
   MONTH(TransactionDate) as [Month],  
   SUM (SalesAmount) as [MonthlySales], 
   DATEPART(m, TransactionDate) as [MonthNumber] 
   from Transactions 
   group by YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate)
) 
select 
a.[Month], a.MonthlySales as [MonthlySales 2018], SUM(b.MonthlySales) as [Cumulative 2018]
from cte a inner join cte b on a.MonthNumber  >= b.MonthNumber 
WHERE (a.[Year]) = 2018   AND  (b.[Year]) = 2018  
group by a.[Month], a.MonthlySales
ORDER by a.[Month]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
With Q 
as
(
   Select DatePart(yyyy,TransactionDate) 'Year',DatePart(m,TransactionDate) 'Month',  sum(SalesAmount) 'Sales'
   From Transactions 
   Group by DatePart(yyyy,TransactionDate),DatePart(m,TransactionDate)
) 
Select q.Year,q.Month,( Select sum(q1.Sales)
                                From Q q1
                                Where q1.Year=q.Year
                                    And  q1.Month <= q.Month
                                ) 'Cumulative Sale'
From Q q
Order by q.Year,q.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use aggregation and window functions:

```
select datename(month, transaction_date) as mon,
       sum(salesAmount) as monthly_sales,
       sum(salesAumount) over (order by min(transaction_date)) as running_amount
from transactions t
where t.transaction_date >= '2018-01-01' and
      t.transaction_date < '2019-01-01'
group by datename(month, transaction_date)
order by min(transaction_date);
```